# View helper with Rails returns the wrong value [Rails, Ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

I am trying to write a view helper but it's not returning the correct thing.

```
def table_layout_for(object, *attrs)
  content_tag :table, :class => "layout" do
    for a in attrs
      content_tag :th do
        object.class.human_attribute_name(a)
      end
      content_tag :td do
        object.send(a) if object.respond_to?(a)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### This problem:

```
<%= table_layout_for(@user, :email, :full_name, :business_name, :phone_number) %>
```

### Returns this:

```
[:email, :full_name, :business_name, :phone_number]
```

### I'd like it to return this:

```
<table class="layout"> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <td>paulmacek@gmail.com</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Full name</th> 
    <td>Paul Macek</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Business name</th> 
    <td>2bynight</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Phone number</th> 
    <td>555-423-1245</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the content return by your block in your content_tag is your array, not all content_tag.

You need made :

```
def table_layout_for(object, *attrs)
  content_tag :table, :class => "layout" do
    ret = ''
    for a in attrs
      ret += content_tag :th do
        object.class.human_attribute_name(a)
      end
      ret += content_tag :td do
        object.send(a) if object.respond_to?(a)
      end
    end
    ret
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought this had something to do with multiple returns. Thanks, @shingara :)